# Why is isBefore() not working with a different timeszone in dayjs()?

Tags: javascript, timezone, dayjs

I have an expiry date time (expiryDate which is in mysql date time format) which is always in the Mountain Standard time zone.  I need to see if we have passed the expiry date in the browser - which may be in a different time zone.

Here is my code:

```
let expireTimeMountain = new dayjs(expiryDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
let currentTimeMountain = new dayjs().tz("America/Edmonton");

let expiredFlag = expireTimeMountain.isBefore(currentTimeMountain);
```

but this does not work.  I think the currentTimeMountain is not being processed in the correct time zone.

Here is my debug code:

```
console.log(expiredFlag);

console.log(expireTimeMountain.format('ddd, MMM D, YYYY h:mm A'));
console.log(currentTimeMountain.format('ddd, MMM D, YYYY h:mm A'));
```

and this returns:

```
true
Fri, Feb 25, 2022 9:05 AM
Fri, Feb 25, 2022 8:48 AM
```

and so my expiry time is 9:05am and the current time is 8:48am, so expiry flag should be false.

Can anyone see my issue?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where you're telling `dayjs` that `expireTimeMountain` is in any particular time zone.

Comment: expireTimeMountain is stored in the Mountain Standard time zone already (which is where the server is located)

Comment: Hmm... it's just initialized with `new dayjs(expiryDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`, and I think it would be *much* clearer if you'd specify the time zone there rather than relying on the default time zone (which may be modified by other aspects of the system). I'd *start* by using `new dayjs(expiryDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', "America/Edmonton");`

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.  expiryDate is a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss and does not have any time zone information associated with it.  I did what you said and it doesn't make a difference.  I am going to get rid of all of this and change my expiry date to a timestamp instead.  Much simpler - still I wish I knew what I was missing...

Comment: "expiryDate is a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss and does not have any time zone information associated with it" - which is precisely *why* I was suggesting explicitly specifying the time zone. Sorry it didn't help - I'm not a Javascript developer so I can't really go any further. I've tried to use jsfiddle, but I can't get anywhere. If you're able to include a fiddle in the question, I can experiment with it...